# How to get all videos titles in a youtube channgel using Youtube Data API v3?

Tags: python-3.x, youtube, youtube-api, google-api-python-client, youtube-data-api

I'm working on extracting titles of all videos in a youtube channel using Youtube Data API v3.

I followed snippets from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/python

I'm getting a number when I query for `['statistics']['videoCount']`

But when I search for the actual channel in youtube, it is giving a different number for count of videos.

Let's say I'm trying for channel whose ID is - **UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ**

The `['statistics']['videoCount']` is giving **19**

However if I search for the channel **Post Malone** on youtube, it has **36** videos in it. Where am I going wrong?

Does the `['statistics']['videoCount']` actually give exact number of videos in a youtube channel?

Here's my code:

```
from pprint import pprint
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import os

YOUTUBE_API_KEY = os.environ.get('YOUTUBE_API_KEY')
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=YOUTUBE_API_KEY)

lis = ['UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ']
for i in lis:
    channels_response = youtube.channels().list(part='statistics', id=i).execute()
    print(i, channels_response['items'][0]['statistics']['videoCount'])
for i in lis:
    channels_response = youtube.channels().list(part='contentDetails', id=i).execute()
    for channel in channels_response['items']:
        uploads_list_id = channel["contentDetails"]["relatedPlaylists"]["uploads"]
        playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list(
            playlistId=uploads_list_id,
            part="snippet",
            maxResults=50
          )
        while playlistitems_list_request:
            playlistitems_list_response = playlistitems_list_request.execute()
            for playlist_item in playlistitems_list_response["items"]:
                # pprint(playlist_item)
                title = playlist_item["snippet"]["title"]
                video_id = playlist_item["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"]
                print(title, video_id)
            playlistitems_list_request = youtube.playlistItems().list_next(
                playlistitems_list_request, playlistitems_list_response
            )
```

Comment: The title of your question says: `How to get all **videos titles** in a youtube channel`, but in your question you ask for the **video count**...I don't understand which is your exactly question. Which is the URL of the request you're using? - notice that some videos might not be available *(maybe the YouTube channel set such videos as not available for embed)*, your youtube channel example has indeed 35 videos, but, [see its 19 videos available "i.e public"](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ) = the same as returned by the API.

Comment: I'm printing the number of videos first and then titles of all those videos. I didn't get you when you say not available for embed. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Sukumar, some videos are not able to be embed *(due its owner disable such option)* and this might be a reason why such videos are not counted. Other option is that those videos are private and, YouTube API will show only **public** information. I'll post an answer based in your comment, but, the answer will show the request and its results, not python code *(since I don't know about Python)*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're printing the number of videos from a given YouTube Channel *(by using its `channel_id`)*.

Once you have the `channel_id`, use this request for retrieve the following data:

- The number of uploaded videos *(i.e. its `videoCount`)*.
- The `playlistid` of the playlist that has the uploaded videos.

This is the request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&id=UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ&fields=items(contentDetails%2Cid%2Csnippet(country%2Cdescription%2Ctitle)%2Cstatistics%2Cstatus)%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CtokenPagination&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

These are the results of the YouTube channel: [Post Malone](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ)

You can test these results in the [Google API Explorer demo](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails%252Cstatistics&id=UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ&fields=items(contentDetails%252Cid%252Csnippet(country%252Cdescription%252Ctitle)%252Cstatistics%252Cstatus)%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination&_h=2&):

```
{
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "id": "UCeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ",
   "snippet": {
    "title": "Post Malone",
    "description": "The official Post Malone YouTube Channel.\nwww.postmalone.com"
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "relatedPlaylists": {
     "uploads": "UUeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ",
     "watchHistory": "HL",
     "watchLater": "WL"
    }
   },
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "967939106",
    "commentCount": "0",
    "subscriberCount": "11072809",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "19"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

Check these two values: `uploads` and `videoCount`.

If you enter to the [Post Malone's uploaded videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=UUeLHszkByNZtPKcaVXOCOQQ), you'll get that he has indeed, 19 uploaded videos *(the same quantity as shown in the `videoCount` value)*.

---

In your question you said:

> However if I search for the channel Post Malone on youtube, it has 36
>   videos in it. Where am I going wrong?

I don't think you're doing anything wrong, just you don't have the complete spectrum. You see, if you check some of its `playlists`, you'll see that the 35 videos corresponds to these playlists:

- [Music](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLegvV8yC11jZs8GEM7nEge2wRUU7ADcIV) = 33 videos.
- [More about the artist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLegvV8yC11jZlmZ_WcN-2g0BYEd39Zrkz) = 2 videos.

All his 35 videos are shown in his ["videos" tab](https://www.youtube.com/user/postmalone/videos?sort=dd&view=0&shelf_id=0) in his channel.

To sum it up, the 19 videos corresponds to his 19 uploaded videos *(that are grouped in his "uploads" playlist)*. If you want retrieve all his videos, one option you have is retrieve all the playlists that the YouTube channel has.

For this case, those videos aren't in is channel really, but in a separate autogenerated YouTube channel, hence, the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

This code snippet lets you extract all video titles from a youtube playlist:

```py
import re 
import requests

url = "https://www.your_playlist_url.com"

r = requests.get(url)

code = r.text

titles = re.findall("simpleText":"[^"]*"},"index", code)

for i in titles: print(i[13: -9])`
```

It just takes the HTML and filters out the video titles, which are stored in a complicated javascript object.