# YouTube API - User upload playlist different from real upload videos

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've used this API to get the user uploads playlist ID:

`https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=contentDetails&id=UCr3B2QXnjrKkAIsJhxTJHuA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.

I've used this other API to get the user videos from the uploads playlist (based on the previous API call):

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUr3B2QXnjrKkAIsJhxTJHuA&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.

This method works perfectly with some channels, but if the channel belongs to a musician it has some problems.

For example with this user     `https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCr3B2QXnjrKkAIsJhxTJHuA` it gives you only 12 video but if you go on his channel on the video tab you can see that it clearly has more than 12 video: [Rkomiofficial](https://www.youtube.com/c/Rkomiofficial/videos)

I've tried with this other method with the same results:

`https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?channelId=UCr3B2QXnjrKkAIsJhxTJHuA&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`.

EDIT:
I found out that all the videos of that channel that are not found by the API's have "VEVO" in their thumbnail. Does youtube API not find music video or something?
[image: Only "Io in tour - Episodio III" can be found with the API's]

Comment: Your first call doesnt return playlist it returns channel stats.  **A playlist resource represents a YouTube playlist. A playlist is a collection of videos that can be viewed sequentially and shared with other users.**   a play list does not return all of the videos for a channel.

Comment: @DaImTo but that's how Google said we should get all user uploads from a channel: [link]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RjUlmco7v2M

Comment: @DaImTo: I fixed the OP's text; it should be clearer now. In my opinion, he's expressing a legitimate issue.

Comment: @Alessandro Craciun: I confirm reproducing your issue above. You may well try to report this to Google too, through its [own issue tracker site](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: @stvar On https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support it's written to use StackOverflow to get support, and no mention at all on that site. 
From https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker: "Issue Tracker is a tool used internally at Google to track bugs and feature requests during product development. It is available outside of Google for use by external public and partner users who need to collaborate with Google teams on specific projects.". Is this the right tool?

Comment: @Riccardo Messineo: On the [very page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/support) you quoted above is to be found the following text: ***[Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=186600&template=874803)
Something wrong? Send us a bug report!*** Unfortunately, time and again, due to misleading Google claims, it's needed to clear things out: SO is not Google support. SO is independent of Google. Google has its own support and bug tracker sites. These are well-known facts.

Comment: @Riccardo Messineo: SO is about programming. Under the SO's tags [tag:youtube-api] and [tag:youtube-data-api], one will find a plethora of answer to questions pertaining to YouTube APIs. Mostly *programming* questions; but, at times, answers are provided to things laying somewhere in between *programming* APIs and *configuration* of API accesses.

Comment: @Riccardo Messineo: In my experience of monitoring these YouTube API tags (the last couple of years) and according to the experience of other SO users (spanning a much wider time frame than mine), there's no SO user that assumes publicly answering SO questions in Google's name (the contrary used to be true well back in the past).

Comment: @stvar Oh my God... I didn't see it at all... Poor architecture of information in my humble opinion on that page! Thank you!

Comment: @AlessandroCraciun please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029953/12511801) - it's a "problem" with certain channels.