# Youtube data API - mismatch between number of videos in channel statistics and "uploads" playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I need to retrieve full set of videos from particular Youtube channel.
I do this using [Youtube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) and `google-api-python-client` package.

Basically, I get ID of "uploads" playlist, then use `playlistItems.list` API method. The problem is, Youtube API doesn't seem to return full list of videos.
If I try to get channel statistics ( using `channels.list` method ) it says channel has 32356 videos. However, `playlistItems.list` returns just 19989 videos.

Channel ID in question is `UCdl_gZZR6BtKi45eHFGAduw`. When I perform [`channels.list` request](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22contentDetails%2Cstatistics%22%5D%2C%22id%22%3A%5B%22UCdl_gZZR6BtKi45eHFGAduw%22%5D%7D)
it returns `statistics.videoCount = 32356`. However, when I use [`playlistItems.list` method](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%22%5D%2C%22playlistId%22%3A%22UUdl_gZZR6BtKi45eHFGAduw%22%7D)
it says there are 19989 videos in total ( `pageInfo.totalResults` field ).

So I'm wondering why such a big difference between channel stats and number of videos? I was thinking that maybe some videos are private, or were deleted and channel stats wasn't updated, but such a big difference feels excessive.

Comment: Probably it's due some unique feature of the channel itself. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029953/12511801) for more info.