# Data is strange when calling youtube/v3/playlistItems API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

```
Hi https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems 
I have something to check about the API response data.

[(Completed) Live Streaming] is exposed when you search 
with param data playlist ID 'UUpqmToOxz7DlLVRg3MCTalw'.

This data is data that ended in 2016.

It is also not exposed on the YouTube channel of the account.

Under what conditions will that data be exposed?

I don't want to be exposed.

Please let me know if you need additional API information.
```

What I've tried is to check the return data when calling the "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems" API.

The API exposes data that is not present in the YouTube channel.

Comment: I'm sorry, but, I don't understand your issue. When I query that youtube channel using the API, I get a single uploaded video - `XeOIPjA-tw0` - I cannot see youtube right now, but, probably you're watching that this youtube channel has more videos. If so, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55029953/12511801) for more information about how you can get all videos on a youtube channel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, I didn't think it was the answer I wanted, so I asked you again after finding a reproduction route.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74298558/excluding-youtube-v3-playlistitems-api-call-videos-live-streaming-offline-de Thank you very much.